# Using Dynarch's JSCalendar 1.0, how do I set the default date to yesterday

Tags: javascript, jscalendar

I am using JSCalendar, version 1.0, from dynarch.com
I have 3 calendars on the page, and for one of them, I need to make the default date set as yesterday.

The code that I use to set up the calendar looks like this:

```
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField  : "endDate",         // ID of the input field
        ifFormat    : "%Y%m%d",    // the date format
        button      : "calendarTriggerEndDate",       // ID of the button
        timeFormat  : 24,
        showsTime   :false,
        displayArea :"reportEndDate",
        daFormat    : "%b %d, %Y"
    });
```

I have tried adding a "date" parameter, but it doesn't seem to do the job.  Perhaps, it could need to be formatted differently.

How do I set the default date?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't found a "clean" method to do this either, so this is how I've had to resort to a manual fix for this problem:

```
<input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cTime = new Date();
  var defDate = cTime.toISOString();
  defDate = defDate.substring(0, defDate.indexOf("T"));
  document.getElementById('StartDate').value = defDate;
  document.write('<img src="icon.png" id="trigger" align="Cal" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle" />');
  var c = Calendar.setup( {
    inputField  : "StartDate",
    ifFormat    : "%Y-%m-%d",
    button      : "trigger"
  });
</script>
```